# Firefox 35.0 cutting off the title tooltip if text is long

Tags: html, css, firefox

Title pretty much says it all.

If I have a `title` attribute with a long text in it (while the HTML element is truncated) the tooltip gets cut off. This happens only in Firefox (only tested version 35.0) from what I see.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7m58grkg/1/

Also a screenshot of the fiddle in firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hVOS.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can fix that in your (html/css) code. It's a known bug in Firefox. There is an [Addon (Long Titles by Xavier Robin)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/long-titles/) that might fix that problem, but sadly only in the clients browser, which probably wont help you that much.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've looked up the bugs you mentioned and from what I see they say it's fixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218223 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45375 . How come nobody complained recently about them in the comments pane?

Comment: @Zubzob hi, i run into this issue too. have you got a work round yet?