# Firefox Tooltip inconsistency (when large text is given)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, tooltip, microsoft-edge

According to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062248/firefox-35-0-cutting-off-the-title-tooltip-if-text-is-long), this is a Firefox bug that has been resolved resolved:

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45375
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218223

```html
<div title="jgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkejgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gkjgjgnfmfnfjdbfkfhrbmfludgdbmfldjrnmgfkvjmrmffgkhfbrkfjgbfjhbfhfghfmjfjnrjrjntmvlgjtmg,lgk,gk" class="hello">
This is a test of a tooltip that could potentially go off of the edge of the screen. What it should do is wrap at the edge of the screen to the next line. It is debateable whether or not a line break in the code should put a new line into the tooltip, since that could be used to make a list. The HTML 4.01 spec says newlines should be treated as whitespace in all attributes that take CDATA, but TITLE takes text, not necessarily CDATA. This has all been in one line up to this point. Now for a newline:
This is a new line. Now for a double newline
</div>
```

(Open in Firefox)

How do I solve this?

Comment: Your example is effectively a very long single word as there are no spaces so truncation seems reasonable.  With real text it works & wraps: http://jsfiddle.net/7m58grkg/37/  If you want different consistent behavior use a tooltip library, there are many.

Comment: i have a use case where it has 128 alphabets.. can you make it  work for at least 128 characters without space

Comment: So there are no spaces in your 128 character string? Seems an odd thing to show to a user in such a way that all they can do is look at it in a tip. Consider adding spaces/new line to the value.

Comment: The example is somewhat contrived. Do you have a real-world example of very long text with no whitespace like this? Since strings can be *arbitrarily* long, force-wrapping isn't a perfect solution. A huge+wrapped tooltip can end up covering the entire screen. That's not what they're meant for. Truncating after some max width seems appropriate to me (although there should be a visible ellipsis in such cases).